# Перенос столбца из df в столбец np.array матрицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Есть df с несколькими столбцами. Нужно записать их в матрицу numpy точно так же, "по-столбцово" Но документация дает лишь описание заполнения матрицы numpy строками. Можно как то записать столбец из df в np.array сразу и без транспонирования?

Буду благодарен в том числе за ссылки на релевантные вопросы возникавшие ранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример.

Исходный DF:

```
In [113]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5), columns=list('abcde'))

In [114]: df
Out[114]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

`DataFrame.values` возвращает Numpy array той же размерности:

```
In [115]: df.values
Out[115]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

для выбранных столбцов:

```
In [116]: df[['a','c','e']].values
Out[116]:
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 5,  7,  9],
       [10, 12, 14],
       [15, 17, 19],
       [20, 22, 24]])
```

тип `df.values`:

```
In [117]: type(df.values)
Out[117]: numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: Спасибо, MaxU) именно твоего ответа ждал)

Comment: @StepanSokol, всегда рад помочь (-: